# SQL multi query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help to do it right in one query (if it possible).
(this is a theoretical example and I assume the presence of events in event_name(like registration/action etc)

I have 3 colums:

```
-user_id
-event_timestamp
-event_name
```

From this 3 columns we need to create new table with 4 new columns:

```
-user year and month registration time
-number of new user registration in this month
-number of users who returned to the second calendar month after registration
-return probability
```

Result must be looks like this:

```
2019-1 | 1 | 1 | 100%
2019-2 | 3 | 2 | 67%
2019-3 | 2 | 0 | 0%
```

What I've done now:
I'm use this toy example of my possible main table:

```
CREATE TABLE `main` (
  `event_timestamp` timestamp,
  `user_id` int(10),
  `event_name` char(12)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `main` (`event_timestamp`, `user_id`, `event_name`) VALUES
  ('2019-01-23 20:02:21.550', '1', 'registration'),
  ('2019-01-24 20:03:21.550', '2', 'action'),
  ('2019-02-21 20:04:21.550', '3', 'registration'),
  ('2019-02-22 20:05:21.550', '4', 'registration'),
  ('2019-02-23 20:06:21.550', '5', 'registration'),
  ('2019-02-23 20:06:21.550', '1', 'action'),
  ('2019-02-24 20:07:21.550', '6', 'action'),
  ('2019-03-20 20:08:21.550', '3', 'action'),
  ('2019-03-21 20:09:21.550', '4', 'action'),
  ('2019-03-22 20:10:21.550', '9', 'action'),
  ('2019-03-23 20:11:21.550', '10', 'registration'),
  ('2019-03-22 20:10:21.550', '4', 'action'),
  ('2019-03-22 20:10:21.550', '5', 'action'),
  ('2019-03-24 20:11:21.550', '11', 'registration');
```

I'm trying to test some queries to create 4 new columns:

This is for column #1, we select month and year from timestamp where action is registration (as I guess), but I need to sum it for month (like 2019-11, 2019-12)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(event_timestamp, '%Y-%m') AS column_1 FROM main
WHERE event_name='registration';
```

For column #2 we need to sum users with even_name registration in this month for every month, or.. we can trying for searching first time activity by user_id, but I don't know how to do this.

Here is some thinks about it...

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS user_count
FROM main
GROUP BY MONTH(event_timestamp);
```

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS user_count FROM main
WHERE event_name='registration';
```

For column #3 we need to compare `user_id` with the `event_name` `registration` and last month event with any event of the second month so we get users who returned for the next month.

Any idea how to create this query?

This is how to calc column #4

```
SELECT *,
ROUND ((column_3/column_2)*100) AS column_4
FROM main;
```

Comment: @dale-k; There are some strange symbols for SQL Server in the code.

Comment: @DaleK; I mean it's not SQL Server statement (T-SQL), not mentioning the errors or whatever.

Comment: I'm use this online db-fiddle with MySQL v5.7

Comment: @XAMT ok, done, i'm sorry.

Comment: Can you show us, for this data you have at the start, what would be your result data ? Thanks!

Comment: @VBoka Result  (4 new colums) must be looks like this: 2019-10 | 2468| 1530| 62% All i've done now its a parts of this result.

Comment: Ok, I see that, but you have given us 10 rows of data, correct? And in that data there is no 10th month  and there is no way you can get result of 2468 for column #2 if you use that example data right? So what I ask you is can you give us a result from this example data ?  Maybe I do not understand something ?

Comment: @Mavic, could you please elaborate on the result for column 3? it is a bit unclear, since your example has unique user for every entry.

Comment: @VBoka okey, i'm change toy example now, its need to be result like this: 

```2019-1 | 1 | 1 | 100%,
2019-2 | 3 | 2 | 67%,
2019-3 | 2 | 0 | 0%```   I cant give it like a table in this comment :/

Comment: @JoPapou13 its not easy to explain... and for now i dont know how to do it right. But, this column its people who do registration in month 2019-01 and have activity in 2019-02 (so he is returned)

Comment: @Mavic, one more thing, is your version: MySQL v5.7  as you mentioned in your comment?

Comment: @VBoka its any strong changes? i'm used online dbfiddle and sqlfiddle (mysql 5.6 and 5.7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you will find the following answer helpful.

The first column is the extraction of year and month. The `new_users` column is the `COUNT` of the unique user ids when the action is 'registration' since the user can be duplicated from the `JOIN` as a result of taking multiple actions the following month. The `returned_users` column is the number of users who have an action in the next month from the registration. The `returned_users` column needs a `DISTINCT` clause since a user can have multiple actions during one month. The final column is the probability that you asked from the two previous columns.

The `JOIN` clause is a self-join to bring the users that had at least one action the next month of their registration.

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(A.event_timestamp),'-',MONTH(A.event_timestamp)),
  COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN  A.event_name LIKE 'registration' THEN A.user_id END)) AS new_users,
  COUNT(DISTINCT B.user_id) AS returned_users,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN  A.event_name LIKE 'registration' THEN A.user_id END))=0 THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT B.user_id)/COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN  A.event_name LIKE 'registration' THEN A.user_id END))*100 END AS My_Ratio
FROM main AS A
LEFT JOIN main AS B
ON A.user_id=B.user_id AND MONTH(A.event_timestamp)+1=MONTH(B.event_timestamp)
  AND A.event_name='registration' AND B.event_name='action'
GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(A.event_timestamp),'-',MONTH(A.event_timestamp))
```

Comment: its so close, but column 'returned_users' didnt work, its must be like this with my toy example ```2019-1 | 1 | 1 | 100%, 2019-2 | 3 | 2 | 67%, 2019-3 | 2 | 0 | 0%``` but its column same 'new_users'.

Comment: @Mavs, are your returned users all the users which have action?

Comment: in your query its all users, in task its users who have 'action' in previous month

Comment: @Mavs, I can not understand why you expect 2 users in the return column for '2019-2'. The users 3,4,5 are registered in February and have an action in March. Should not that column have 3 as return?

Comment: look at user id action, in example ```('2019-02-23 20:06:21.550', '1', 'action'),``` its user id #1 registered in month#1 and in month #2 he have 'action', so he is need to be counted in column like 'returned'. We need to look for ppl who have 'action' in the next month after registration and count them.

Comment: @Mavic, user 3,4,5 are registered in month 2 and they have action on month 3. The returned users should be 3 for month 2 as in the first. Could you check your expected output?

Comment: yeah, im sorry, its my fail, i didnt see user id #3 in action. Your example is work, but give a incorrect ratio, when returned users =0

Comment: @Mavic, updated the code to return 0 when there is no new user in that month. The problem is when you have to divide with 0 new users, a CASE WHEN was used to give the proper result

Answer (score 2):

What we will do is to use window functions and aggregation -- window functions to get the earliest registration date.  Then some conditional aggregation.

One challenge is the handling of calendar months.  To handle this, we will truncate the dates to the beginning of the month to facilitate the date arithmetic:

```
select yyyymm_reg, count(*) as regs_in_month,
       sum( month_2 > 0 ) as visits_2months,
       avg( month_2 > 0 ) as return_rate_2months
from (select m.user_id, m.yyyymm_reg,
             max( (timestampdiff(month, m.yyyymm_reg, m.yyyymm) = 1) ) as month_1,
             max( (timestampdiff(month, m.yyyymm_reg, m.yyyymm) = 2) ) as month_2,
             max( (timestampdiff(month, m.yyyymm_reg, m.yyyymm) = 3) ) as month_3
      from (select m.*,
                   cast(concat(extract(year_month from event_timestamp), '01') as date) as yyyymm,
                   cast(concat(extract(year_month from min(case when event_name = 'registration' then event_timestamp end) over (partition by user_id)), '01') as date) as yyyymm_reg
            from main m
           ) m
      where m.yyyymm_reg is not null
      group by m.user_id, m.yyyymm_reg
     ) u
group by u.yyyymm_reg;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94dced0e4bf23f8f309f879528b563ca) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Interesting, im didnt know about window functions yet. Its full code? Its give me an errors.

Comment: @Mavic . . . I fixed a couple of typos and added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: checked result, and column#3 and column#4 didnt work

Comment: @Mavic . . . You have to adjust the  months to be what you want.  I don't really know what  "users who returned to the second calendar month after registration" is supposed to mean.

Comment: as I guess its 'action' in event_name (if someone who done registration on last month do some action in second - its tells us that he came back)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, done in T-SQL:

```
;with cte as(

select a.*  from (
select form,user_id,sum(count_regs) as count_regs,sum(count_action) as count_action from (
select FORMAT(event_timestamp,'yyyy-MM') as form,user_id,event_name,
CASE WHEN event_name = 'registration' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as count_regs,
CASE WHEN event_name = 'action' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as count_action from main) a 
group by form,user_id) a)





select final.form,final.count_regs,final.count_action,((CAST(final.count_action as float)/(CASE WHEN final.count_regs = '0' THEN '1' ELSE final.count_regs END))*100) as probability  from (
select a.form,sum(a.count_regs) count_regs,CASE WHEN sum(b.count_action) is null then '0' else sum(b.count_action) end count_action from cte a 
left join 
cte b 
ON a.user_id = b.user_id and 
DATEADD(month,1,CONVERT(date,a.form+'-01')) = CONVERT(date,b.form+'-01') 
group by a.form ) final where final.count_regs != '0' or final.count_action != '0'
```